# ¿como hacer un diagrama de flujo de las fases de un compilador?

Tags: compilador, diagrama-de-flujo, lenguaje-compilado

Se que puede ser algo sencillo, estudio programación, pero voy empezando, y me pidieron hacer un diagrama de flujo de las fases de un compilador, pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo, no le hallo mucho sentido al hacerlo, siento que sería mejor dar una explicación nada más, pero bueno, espero puedan apoyar, gracias.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [esto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilador)

Answer (score 0):

En el comentario de Gabitohh tienes un ejemplo de las fases de compilación, ahí puedes ver los procesos por los que pasa el código en los lenguajes de programación compilados, el objetivo de tu tarea es ilustrarte por los pasos que hay que tomar para obtener el código en ensamblador(máquina).
Para hacer el diagrama puedes usar esta herramienta:
https://creately.com/es/lp/software-de-diagrama-de-flujo/